# How can I resolve the error "The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata" in native Java or Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

The error message:

> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata
> (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater
> than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30). Dependency:
> androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha02.
>
> AAR metadata file: 
> C:\Users\mohammad.zeeshan1.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a20beb0771f59a8ddbbb8d416ea06a9d\jetified-core-ktx-1.7.0-alpha02\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

Comment: (The proposed dupe, unlike this question, has an MCVE)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

I have found the solution. Enter this line of code above package in the app Gradle file.

For Kotlin developers:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of code with a red freehand circle]

For Java developers

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0' }
}
```

Comment: For java developers, remove the `ktx`: `resolutionStrategy {force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'}`

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue on ReactNative. Adding this line didn't work out in my project. Is there more way to solve this issue?

Comment: Why does this work?  I'm really surprised; my project gradle defines the kotlin version as 1.5.10!

Comment: Why do this rather than just downgrade the core-ktx version to 1.6.0? - I am a mobile noob...

Comment: With Arctic Fox this hack no longer seems to work.  I had to bump up the compileSdk from 30 to 31 in build.gradle (app), as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69283902/624814.

Comment: No longer works on Arctic Fox. Android Development is a such a pain in @$$.

Comment: It doesn't even work anymore when creating a default Android project from scratch with a newly installed IntelliJ IDEA. They went from a great tool to something unusable.

Comment: If anyone still stuck. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/74356512/2602054

Comment: This is the correct answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/69283902/123132

Answer (score 262):

Set both `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `31` in your `build.gradle(app)` file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 // <-- This
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        targetSdkVersion 31 // <-- and this too
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: CHECK THIS LIBRARY: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0' CHANGUE TO 1.3.1 VERSION. And fixed with resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0' } also..

Comment: Gradle build is failing after I change this to 31.

Comment: Changing to Compile SDK version to 31 worked for me

Comment: This works for me after also updating ext.kotlin_version inside gradle's build.gradle file to the latest version.

Answer (score 80):

This issue is most often seen with libraries that declare

`implementation androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-beta01`

The `minCompileSdk` is 31, but the `minSdkVersion` is significantly lower.

Increasing the `compileSdk` of your project is enough to fix the issue. There is no need for overrides or even changing the `targetSdk`.

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

...
}
```

Comment: Greate answer. This is the correct solution regarding this issue. Due to fix this issue we can change compile sdk enough. If we change targetSdk then, it will give some other ploblems, thats not need for this issue fix.

Comment: This Answer fixed my issue.

Comment: I agree with @MohamedIbrahim that increasing `compileSdkVersion` alone enough to fix this issue. Hence, This is the best solution

Comment: Didn't resolve for me at all.

Comment: @JCutting8 Not every solution works for every use case, which is why SO has the option to submit more than one answer even when one has been accepted. Best of luck finding the one that works for you.

Comment: @AbandonedCart Actually, it did work, lol. Sorry. My addition to this answer would be to make sure you update the compileSdk verison for the correct module (if you have multiple modules as I did).

Comment: @JCutting8 Multiple modules should still fall under "your project"

Comment: The file to change is located at `/app/build.gradle`. I had to set `compileSdkVersion 32` in order to make it work.

Comment: @DirkSchumacher The folder name may vary. It's whatever build.gradle files fall under the folders listed in the root settings.gradle as included. The question specifically asked about 31, but this is only the latest API for all modules and libraries included. In your case, that is 32.

Comment: yes, currently it requires minCompileSdk=34. No need to change target sdk

Answer (score 46):

Finally, I can solve my issue.

What was the problem?

I had the following dependency in one module -

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

but other modules, including the app module, had the following dependency

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

Converting

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

to

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

solved my problem.

Comment: For me it was suggesting version 1.6.0 as soon as I cleared the "+" and it then compiled with that version. So I think you should check for the auto suggestion and use this value then.

Comment: @tickietackie that's right same here

Comment: This worked!  Thank you!  Thank you!   Thank you!  I burned a lot of time trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 16):

You're going to need to update your compile SDK to 31. It *sounds* like it's currently set to 30. In your Gradle files there should be something like `compileSdk` in the `android` block.

Bump that up to 31. If that's an issue for some reason, you can also bump down your dependencies to versions that don't require that compile SDK version.

Comment: Is there any other solution? I can't do this because some dependencies break after doing this.

Comment: Facing same problem .. any solution keeping my compile sdk version 30 ?

Comment: use implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0"

Answer (score 15):

I had this issue on a react-native project that was working a few days ago, suddenly I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDevDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha02.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/me/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ed22ee8b86d25659bbef1e9ee203b75c/jetified-core-ktx-1.7.0-alpha02/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0-alpha02.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/me/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/23234efc7e9de9bfe6a3fea85a6072ef/core-1.7.0-alpha02/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

After reading the error message I understood that the problem was `androidx.core:core-ktx` so I searched more about it and found that a new version has just been released last September 01 https://androidx.tech/artifacts/core/core-ktx/ which was https://androidx.tech/artifacts/core/core-ktx/1.7.0-alpha02 which has `targetSdkVersion = 31`

I ran `grep -r "androidx.core:core-ktx" node_modules` and found that I have one dependency that has `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"` which will install the latest version when I install the app. I can't just update to 31 because it seems to break the codes of some of my dependencies, I will get:

```
unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.SharedNameTable$NameImpl)
```

Which I don't really know how to fix and can't find any lead, it's most probably because it's new.

As a workaround, on file `android/app/build.gradle`

Add the following block on before `android {}` block.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha01' }
}
```

After doing this, it worked for me. It will force all `androidx.core:core-ktx` to be `1.7.0-alpha01`

Comment: I ran `grep -r "androidx.core:core-ktx" node_modules` and got no output. Still I am getting this error.

Comment: I just had this error while building for android on my react-native project, it wasn't due to `androidx.core:core-ktx` but instead due to `androidx.browser:browser`. This comes from the library `react-native-inappbrowser-reborn`, which specifies the android package version to be 1+. After a gradle sync, `androidx.browser` version 1.4.0-alpha01 is brought in, causing this error. A fix is suggested here  https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues/298

Comment: For what it's worth, the error you received about MODULE etc will resolve with JDK11, JDK8 does not work well with the API31 android sdk levels

Answer (score 13):

When using [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) navigation, I had this problem...

I was using `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha07`

So I solved it by using another version:

```
`androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha06`
```

Comment: The problem exists in alpha07 and alpha08. Changing it to 06 fixed my problem. (I wanted to compile it with SDK 30, but never versions require SDK 31)

Comment: Downgrading version is not a good solution.

Comment: Dependency: androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and found out the issues was with the lifecycle library.

I changed from the beta version,

> androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.4.0beta1

to current stable version,

> androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.3.1

Check the [Android website for versions](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle).

Comment: Now even the new stable release 2.4.0 is throwing this error.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me without increasing compile version. Thanks