# material-1.5.0-alpha03\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, material-components-android, multiview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral0">@android:color/system_neutral1_1000</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral10">@android:color/system_neutral1_900</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral100">@android:color/system_neutral1_0</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral20">@android:color/system_neutral1_800</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral30">@android:color/system_neutral1_700</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral40">@android:color/system_neutral1_600</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral50">@android:color/system_neutral1_500</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral60">@android:color/system_neutral1_400</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral70">@android:color/system_neutral1_300</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral80">@android:color/system_neutral1_200</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral90">@android:color/system_neutral1_100</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral95">@android:color/system_neutral1_50</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral99">@android:color/system_neutral1_10</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant0">@android:color/system_neutral2_1000</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant10">@android:color/system_neutral2_900</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant100">@android:color/system_neutral2_0</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant20">@android:color/system_neutral2_800</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant30">@android:color/system_neutral2_700</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant40">@android:color/system_neutral2_600</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant50">@android:color/system_neutral2_500</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant60">@android:color/system_neutral2_400</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant70">@android:color/system_neutral2_300</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant80">@android:color/system_neutral2_200</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant90">@android:color/system_neutral2_100</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant95">@android:color/system_neutral2_50</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant99">@android:color/system_neutral2_10</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary0">@android:color/system_accent1_1000</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary10">@android:color/system_accent1_900</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary100">@android:color/system_accent1_0</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary20">@android:color/system_accent1_800</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary30">@android:color/system_accent1_700</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary40">@android:color/system_accent1_600</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary50">@android:color/system_accent1_500</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary60">@android:color/system_accent1_400</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary70">@android:color/system_accent1_300</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary80">@android:color/system_accent1_200</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary90">@android:color/system_accent1_100</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary95">@android:color/system_accent1_50</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary99">@android:color/system_accent1_10</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary0">@android:color/system_accent2_1000</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary10">@android:color/system_accent2_900</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary100">@android:color/system_accent2_0</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary20">@android:color/system_accent2_800</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary30">@android:color/system_accent2_700</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary40">@android:color/system_accent2_600</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary50">@android:color/system_accent2_500</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary60">@android:color/system_accent2_400</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary70">@android:color/system_accent2_300</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary80">@android:color/system_accent2_200</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary90">@android:color/system_accent2_100</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary95">@android:color/system_accent2_50</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary99">@android:color/system_accent2_10</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary0">@android:color/system_accent3_1000</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary10">@android:color/system_accent3_900</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary100">@android:color/system_accent3_0</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary20">@android:color/system_accent3_800</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary30">@android:color/system_accent3_700</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary40">@android:color/system_accent3_600</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary50">@android:color/system_accent3_500</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary60">@android:color/system_accent3_400</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary70">@android:color/system_accent3_300</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary80">@android:color/system_accent3_200</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary90">@android:color/system_accent3_100</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary95">@android:color/system_accent3_50</color>
    <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary99">@android:color/system_accent3_10</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_background">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral10</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_inverse_on_surface">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral20</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_inverse_primary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary40</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_inverse_surface">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral90</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_background">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral90</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_primary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary20</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_primary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary90</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_secondary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary20</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_secondary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary90</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_surface">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral90</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_surface_variant">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant80</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_tertiary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary20</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_tertiary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary90</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_outline">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant60</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_primary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary80</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_primary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary30</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_secondary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary80</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_secondary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary30</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_surface">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral10</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_surface_variant">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant30</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_tertiary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary80</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_tertiary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary30</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_background">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral99</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_inverse_on_surface">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral95</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_inverse_primary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary80</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_inverse_surface">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral20</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_background">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral10</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_primary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary100</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_primary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary10</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_secondary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary100</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_secondary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary10</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_surface">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral10</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_surface_variant">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant30</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_tertiary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary100</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_tertiary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary10</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_outline">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant50</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_primary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary40</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_primary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_primary90</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_secondary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary40</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_secondary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_secondary90</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_surface">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral99</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_surface_variant">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral_variant90</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_tertiary">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary40</color>
    <color name="m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_tertiary_container">@color/m3_ref_palette_dynamic_tertiary90</color>
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.Material3.DynamicColors.Dark" parent="">
    <!-- Color palettes -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_primary</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryInverse">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_inverse_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_primary_container</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_primary_container</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_secondary_container</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_secondary_container</item>
    <item name="colorTertiary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_tertiary</item>
    <item name="colorOnTertiary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_tertiary</item>
    <item name="colorTertiaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_tertiary_container</item>
    <item name="colorOnTertiaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_tertiary_container</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_background</item>
    <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_background</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_surface</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_surface</item>
    <item name="colorSurfaceVariant">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_surface_variant</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_on_surface_variant</item>
    <item name="colorSurfaceInverse">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_inverse_surface</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurfaceInverse">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_inverse_on_surface</item>
    <item name="colorOutline">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_dark_outline</item>
    <item name="colorError">@color/m3_sys_color_dark_error</item>
    <item name="colorOnError">@color/m3_sys_color_dark_on_error</item>
    <item name="colorErrorContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dark_error_container</item>
    <item name="colorOnErrorContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dark_on_error_container</item>
  </style>
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.Material3.DynamicColors.DayNight" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.DynamicColors.Light"/>
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.Material3.DynamicColors.Light" parent="">
    <!-- Color palettes -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_primary</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryInverse">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_inverse_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_primary_container</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_primary_container</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_secondary_container</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_secondary_container</item>
    <item name="colorTertiary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_tertiary</item>
    <item name="colorOnTertiary">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_tertiary</item>
    <item name="colorTertiaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_tertiary_container</item>
    <item name="colorOnTertiaryContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_tertiary_container</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_background</item>
    <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_background</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_surface</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_surface</item>
    <item name="colorSurfaceVariant">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_surface_variant</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_on_surface_variant</item>
    <item name="colorSurfaceInverse">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_inverse_surface</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurfaceInverse">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_inverse_on_surface</item>
    <item name="colorOutline">@color/m3_sys_color_dynamic_light_outline</item>
    <item name="colorError">@color/m3_sys_color_light_error</item>
    <item name="colorOnError">@color/m3_sys_color_light_on_error</item>
    <item name="colorErrorContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_light_error_container</item>
    <item name="colorOnErrorContainer">@color/m3_sys_color_light_on_error_container</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Here is my `v31/values-v31`

While I'm trying to build this project . I'm frequently getting this error(

> ERROR:C:\Users\Dell.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\66e9dd10963e7a2704a4a2116f19e6fb\material-1.5.0-alpha03\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.)

Solutions I tried
Rebuild project, clean project, Invalidate cache and restart, `enter code here`and also delete and newly create that emulator but nothing worked for me

Answer (score 90):

As described in the [**release notes**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.5.0-alpha03):

The version `1.5.0-alpha03` introduces the new [Material 3 themes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md) and

> Make sure to update your app's [**`compileSdkVersion`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.5.0-alpha03/build.gradle#L22) to **31** when using this version of the library.

Answer (score 70):

**Short answer:**

> To fix the compilation error, make sure to update your app’s `compileSdkVersion` to **31** when using
> fresh versions of the Material Components library.
>
> Or you can downgrade the Material Components library to `1.4.0` or `1.5.0-alpha02`.

**Explanations:**

Starting from version `1.5.0-alpha03`, Material Components library requires **compile SDK version 31** (was raised at commit [40509dc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/40509dc94edb4f710eccbf842ddd5933d640a7b2#diff-49a96e7eea8a94af862798a45174e6ac43eb4f8b4bd40759b5da63ba31ec3ef7R22)).
See [release notes on GitHub](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.5.0-alpha03).

It is required because of the new [Material 3 themes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md) with [dynamic colors](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md#using-dynamic-colors) support.
Starting from Android S (API 31), the framework provides the ability to support dynamic colors in your UI based on the user’s wallpaper or color choice on the device.

Read more about «Material You» wallpaper-based theming system «Monet» which underlies this functionality:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69065800/1816338
https://medium.com/@xch3dx/using-material-you-in-your-app-15ec982eecb4

Comment: this is the correct answer

Comment: This is not helps.

Answer (score 23):

The problem is in the following line:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha03'
```

I used this and got the same error. Replacing it with the following line fixed the problem:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha02')
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it for me too; thank you.

Comment: No, it is not the real solution.

Comment: But that's downgrading a dependency...

Answer (score 14):

I've meet this error, and it's solved. Change or downgrade your dependencies should solve this issue. If you meet this error from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034879/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys), I suggest you should change this both, from :

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
```

to :

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

then, run your app again. I think this method works. This usually happen if you create your new project, but you didn't notice this error, when you trying to run your app.

Comment: thanks, it worked.

Comment: solved my problem

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this error as well, when trying to target API 30 in a Java project. I had tried to downgrade the `appcompat` dependency only and got these errors. Turns out you need to downgrade the `material` dependency as well.

To target **API 30,** you need to downgrade both `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` and `com.google.android.material:material` to older versions.

Change the versions from:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
```

To:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure if this is the solution (it worked for me) but updating the **compileSdk and targerSdk to 31**  alongside with updating these libraries solved the error in my case:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow these Steps

In build.gradle ( Module )

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
        
        
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 30
            buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'
        
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "your package name"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 30
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
        
                testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
        
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
        
        }
        
        dependencies {
        
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
            implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        }
```

In build.gradle (project)    `enter code here`

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

If you are using Firebase,
Dont Forget to Download and paste Json file from Firebase and paste it in app folder.

Comment: You haven't shared any steps. but pasted whole file. Please clarify the steps.

Comment: It's for who are beginners..that code will definitely help them to get rid of this error

Comment: especially to  beginners u should explain what is happening where imo