# What are the hex colors for Android 12?

Tags: android, material-design

I cannot find the hex colors of Android 12 anywhere.

I have tried googling "Android 12 colors", "Android 12 color palette", "Android 12 Hex Colors", but the search results don't return any hex values.

I found this Stackoverflow answer that has the system values:

```
system_accent1_0    
system_accent1_10
system_accent1_50

@android:color/system_accent1_0

Also requires min api 31 to use
```

But I don't know how to get the exact hex values from them.

[How to use new Material You colors announced for Android 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69065334/how-to-use-new-material-you-colors-announced-for-android-12)

[image]

I have also tried the google material site, but they don't have the colors either.

https://m3.material.io/styles/color/overview

https://m2.material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#tools-for-picking-colors

Does anyone know of a webpage that has the exact hex colors?

Comment: Related: [Material design color palette](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32942503/295004) You may also want to explain you use case a bit more as `This value can be overlaid at runtime by OverlayManager RROs.` https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml

Comment: "I cannot find the hex colors of Android 12" -- what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: Sorry my question was a bit confusing, I meant the "Material You" color palette in Android 12. @Morrison The second link is what I was looking for. Thank you!