# Android resource linking failed (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Android resource linking failed (Android Studio)

I installed Android Studio and after creating a project with an empty activity, I got the following errors:

> Android resource linking failed
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:3:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:4:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_900 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:5:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_0 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:6:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_800 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:7:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_700 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:8:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_600 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:9:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_500 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:10:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_400 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:11:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_300 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:12:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_200 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:13:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_100 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:14:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_50 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:15:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_10 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:16:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_1000 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:17:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_900 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:18:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_0 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:19:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_800 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:20:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_700 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:21:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_600 not found.
> com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-23:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:22:
> error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_500 not found.

Comment: what is your compileSdkVersion and targetSdk in gradle?

Comment: and what is your material library version, also with gradle version??

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69044514/material-1-5-0-alpha03-res-values-v31-values-v31-xml35-94-aapt-error-resour, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1324843/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-android-resource-linking-failed.