# One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Hey I am trying to run my application and I am getting this error

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha01' }
    }

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example.listadapter"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.5.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'

    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.12.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.12.0"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6'
}
```

I tried this All Example from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69034879/11560810) it's not working

getting error after installing the application. I just created a new application. I don't understand why this is causing it. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in adavance.

```
One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: /Users/vmodi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b7f9608e476cb2e496993f185af8912c/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: /Users/vmodi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/538fea46e89a6c8a3e3eec533224abb8/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-runtime-ktx-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: /Users/vmodi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6a1f77e99280b09902894e4ae8301047/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-livedata-ktx-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: /Users/vmodi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/41cf6125c3fd7a33d28222cf07d20520/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: /Users/vmodi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/655163560a267a5b16e2f66044d78641/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: /Users/vmodi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1ca84d966e72f2f06b580da1765a55a5/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: /Users/vmodi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3ed4d52253be7f6d85cbabee72c886d3/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: /Users/vmodi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4e8a32482e233cfbbc450e03aabed8dd/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

If i change my `compileSdk 31` it gives me another error.

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, returnDefaultValues=false}.
Execution failed for MockableJarTransform: /Users/vmodi/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-31/android.jar.
Cannot create mockable android.jar
/Users/vmodi/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-31/android.jar
```

Comment: Can you show `Project level build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Change your `compileSdk 30` to 31.

It worked for me!

```
   compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lifecycle"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

In the new version of apps:
Just change the compileSdk from 32 to 33.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just change the compileSdk version to 33 in build.gradle file (app)

```
compileSdk 33
```

Answer (score 2):

compileSdk and targetSdk both should be 31. Have you tried?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please make more obvious what additional insight this post is supposed to contribute when compared to the other existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try to downgrade Kotlin library. I have changed

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
```

and this resolved my error.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0.
The issue is with this dependency, there may be some transitive dependency error. I would suggest use the alpha version of this dependency, worked for me.
Replace with this dependency : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-*:2.4.0-alpha03

Answer (score 1):

This is because you just upgraded Kotlin.

Open SDK Manager, install Android 12 (API 31) or above, then change compileSdkVersion to 31 (or above) and change targetSdkVersion to 31 (or above).

Then you will need to change minSdkVersion to 19 as well.

Comment: This works for me, First download Android 12 (API 31), then change compileSdk and targetSdk to 31 and sync. It works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me setting these two values to API 31 worked

```
commonCompileSdkVersion = 31
commonTargetSdkVersion = 31
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove one dependencies from your Gradle Scripts, then it will be solved.

1. Open your `build.gradle(:app)`
2. Go to dependencies
3. Remove `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'`

After doing this the problem was solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

Previously it was working fine with
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73765479/15614129

Now

In the newly created latest version of apps: Change the **compileSdk** & **targetSdk** from **33 to 34**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still facing this error, change their compileSdk to 33.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had a problem : Every time I run my application the AAR metadata will give me an error  , so I did this an it worked
go to the left side of the screen and there's an option called "Gradle Scripts "
click on it and there will be many options so click on the second one that says "build.gradle module" click on it and go to the last method named "dependencies"
and in the method there is a line :
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
so delete the "  :1.5.1 "
so the line become :     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat'
and it worked for me , I hope it'll work also for you

Answer (score 0):

**This WORKED for me**set compile sdk from 31 to 33

compileSdk 33

```
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.happybirthday"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sept 11, 2023
I got this error. I had just made two changes in build.gradle/app so I undid them, error went away. Here are the two statements with the arrow pointing to the previous value that I restored...

implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0' -> 1.10.1

implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0' -> 1.6.0