# 24 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

Tags: android, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

pls kindly help. I have tried all suggestions on [One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943549/one-or-more-issues-found-when-checking-aar-metadata-values) none worked. I will appreciate your help. It synchronizes successfully but when run build it comes up with error 24 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:
24 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
2. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
3. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
4. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
5. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
6. Dependency 'androidx.compose.material:material-ripple-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
7. Dependency 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
8. Dependency 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
9. Dependency 'androidx.compose.animation:animation-core-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
10. Dependency 'androidx.compose.animation:animation-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
11. Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-data-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
12. Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
13. Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
14. Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-unit-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
15. Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
16. Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-text-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
17. Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-util-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
18. Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-geometry-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
19. Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
20. Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
21. Dependency 'androidx.compose.material:material-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
22. Dependency 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
23. Dependency 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-saveable-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
24. Dependency 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-android:1.6.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-33.

    Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
    plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

    Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
    plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
    compileSdk of at least 34.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).

I have tried all the suggestions on:
[One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943549/one-or-more-issues-found-when-checking-aar-metadata-values)

Below is my code:

```js
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.topgf.aiassist'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.topgf.aiassist"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
//            debuggable true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_ui_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    //Room Database
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'

    // JSON Parsing
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.7.3'


    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2'

    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1"

    //Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.47'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.47'
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0"
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.47'
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.47'


    // Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.6.0'


    def richtext_version = '0.17.0'
    implementation "com.halilibo.compose-richtext:richtext-commonmark:${richtext_version}"
    implementation "com.halilibo.compose-richtext:richtext-ui-material:${richtext_version}"
    implementation "com.halilibo.compose-richtext:richtext-ui-material3:${richtext_version}"

    // Coil
    implementation('io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0')

    // Navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.33.0-alpha'
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-material:0.33.0-alpha'


    //Shimmer Effect
    implementation 'com.valentinilk.shimmer:compose-shimmer:1.0.5'

    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.18.0"

    // Lottie
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:6.1.0'

    // In-App Purchase
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:6.0.1'

    // AdMob
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:22.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.yagmurerdogan:Toastic:1.0.1'


}
```

Comment: Why don't you take the recommended action?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a bunch of libraries that only work with compileSDKVersion 34.  Either upgrade your app to use 34, or downgrade all the libraries to a version that works with 34.

Comment: Thanks so much. I later got the solution. Implemented .R