# Nativescript for android build compile sdk errors

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, nativescript

I setup environment for nativescript android build in 2 tries:

- at first I use auto setup through ns cli, but it fails at the end.
- after that I installed all manualy(android studio, JDK, and env. variables by ns official site instruction).

All this could lead to problems, so I let you know, how I'm getting in to the trouble.

Now I'm calling project build for android by **tns build android** and getting build error:

[image]

I tried to set target version manuali by flat **--compileSdk 31** and got error, like a have't this compile sdk version:

[image]

But my android studio shows next things:

[image]

[image]

If I try to build using **ns build android --compileSdk 30** - it starts but will fail with error at first screenshot.

I already tried to reinstall **Android SDK Build-Tools** and **Android SDK Platform-Tools** in android studio - none changes.

Any ideas how to fix this up?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In project directory -> platform -> app build.gradle -> find "compileSdkVersion" inside android {} and set it value manualy:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
```

If it woun't help, try to look here:

[How can I resolve the error "The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata" in native Java or Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034879/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys)