# Getting following erorr while building my project on android studio using java/firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

Getting the following error while building my project on AndroidStudio using java/firebase.

```
Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.1.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/karankumarbrahmbhatt/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b5fa9469f7b06be98533d290d8caf1ac/navigation-ui-2.5.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.0.
AAR metadata file: /Users/karankumarbrahmbhatt/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ae8dee11299507b69686c1b53569839c/jetified-savedstate-1.2.0/META...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034879/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys
Check out this answer

Comment: Or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed).